# How to increase the weight when it comes to outlier detection

Tags: scikit-learn, outlier

Let's say we have feature A, B, C, D, E to represent one observation in an outlier detection model. We are using scikit-learn outlier detection in our case.

AFAIK, if we normalize all the features, they are as equally important as others.

What if I want to make B very important, e.g. if A, C, D, E increase 20%, the observation might still be considered as normal case while B increases 10%, the observation needs to be marked as an outlier.

Is there any way to increase or decrease features' weight in outlier detection model?

Comment: After normalization multiply B by 2, or at least the difference between B and the expected value for B

Comment: how do I know 2 is the best number to multiply?

Comment: 2 is the factor between the 10% and 20% you mentioned. I'll answer with a more generic method.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at my answer at [Identfying spikes in data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20499/identfying-spikes-in-data/20523#20523)
.

A general method could be to calculate a (moving) average and standard deviation.
Outliers are points that differ more than 3 times the standard deviation.

In your case, B will probably have a standard deviation of 3%, because 10% is considered an outlier. For A, C, D, E, the standard deviation may be 7%, because 20% is not considered an outlier.

Relative importance does not make something an outlier. A large deviation does.

Comment: I am using outlier detection directly from scikit-learn. So my question is that in order to increase B's importance, what I can do before I feed all the features to the algorithm?

Comment: @Shengjie What would 'importance' mean in outliers? Outliers mean that they deviate from the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what exactly outlier detector you use.

`EllipticEnvelope` and `IsolationForest` authomatically adjust to the scale and correlations between variables, so you cannot easily change relative weights of features. With `IsolationForest` you can increase importance of B by just replicating this column several times and so icreasing its relative frequency in the tree splits.

Other algorithms, such as `LocalOutlierFactor` and kernel-based `OneClassSVM` are explicitly based on the Euclidean distance between the points. And distance depends on feature scaling. It means that you can multiply B by some factor after normalization, and its importance will increase by this factor.